# Sentence started with Verb+ing, but it's a really different structure

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context, clauses, reduced-relative-clauses, grammar-myths

In the book *Outliers* by Malcolm Gladwell, I came across this confusing sentence:

> Facing the square is the Palazzo Marchesale, the palace of the Saggese family, once the great landowner of those parts.

I couldn't understand the sentence in terms of grammar because it seems to be reduced. But in reduced sentences, there are generally two sentences. Only one of them is reduced, because both sentences have the same subject. In my quoted sentence there is just one sentence? Could you explain this to me please?

Comment: The "composite" clause *the palace of the Saggese family, once the great landowner of those parts* is an [***appositive*** construction](https://www.chompchomp.com/terms/appositive.htm#:~:text=An%20appositive%20is%20a%20noun,crawling%20across%20the%20kitchen%20table.) *- a noun or noun phrase that renames another noun right beside it.* The default word order for your example would be to *start* with the subject *(**the Palazzo Marchesale**)*, and put the verb element *(**is facing the square**)* at the end of the sentence. It''s called ***fronting*** to put it at the front.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica Thank you so much for your answer. Actually, I didn't know "fronting". With your explanation, I understand why the structure is in reverse of normal usage. I will do some research on "fronting" Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: There is also an apposition in your sentence: Palazzo Marchesale, the palace of the Saggese family,

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica: You should leave that as an answer, not a comment. Comments are for suggesting improvements to the question or requesting clarification.

Comment: Neither of the two answers here (one accepted by OP) mention either "fronting" or "apposition", so it's not obvious to me why what I wrote should have been posted as an "Answer". OP seems to be asking about the syntactic *subject*, which I never addressed because I didn't understand that aspect of the question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Facing the square is the Palazzo Marchesale

This is equivalent to:

> The Palazzo Marchesale is facing the square

The reason the author inverted it is so they could more easily attach the relative clause that follows.

Comment: +1 But the real reason they've inverted it is because *the square* has already been mentioned and the *Palazzo Marchesale* is new to the conversation. In the OP's version it takes pride of place at the end of the sentence :)

Comment: The answer should probably address the structure of the rest of the sentence and help explain its meaning.

Answer (score 8):

The Palazzo *faces* the square (its front forms all or part of one of the four sides). The second phrase explains what the palace is, the third explains who the family are.